# Improper Logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, server, backend

I know this question might sound silly, but this problem is really making a big trouble.

I have a web application made on ASP.NET MVC 4. To enter that application one has to register, after that when the user logs out. It shows the proper message of logging out. But, if the user clicks the **back** button of the browser, It enters back to the user's profile.(It never happens every time, it happens very rarely).

Any type of suggestion is highly anticipated.

If i am not clear enough.Feel free to ask any question regarding this matter.

Please help me.

The credentials gets stored in cookie. I want to store that in cookie, but i want to remove that while logging out.

LogOut Code:

```
  public ActionResult Logout()
        {
Session.Clear();
if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies["xxxx"] != null)
            {
                var c = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["xxxx"];
                c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(c);
            }
            if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies["xxxx"] != null)
            {
                var c = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["xxxx"];
                c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(c);
            }
            HttpContext.Session["var1"] = null;
            HttpContext.Session["var2"] = null;
            HttpContext.Session["var3"] = null;
}
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ the user is logged back in? Can you go to another authenticated page after pressing the 'back' button?

Comment: Yes, the user can go to any authenticated page. That's where the problem lies.@markpsmith.

Comment: What code are you using to log the user out?

Comment: Are you sure that the user isn't just seeing a cached (by the browser) version of their profile page? What happens if they subsequently hit the _Refresh_ button in their browser?

Comment: The user goes to other pages, like account settings and changes his profile picture also. It is not cached @RichardEverett

Comment: Can you edit your question to add more technical information? What sort of authentication are you using? What code runs when the user clicks _Logout_?

Comment: I was expecting to see some kind of authentication used, e.g: `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()`. What are you using to manage authentication?

Comment: No Authentication is used @markpsmith

Comment: PLEASE stop doing "authentication" like this. Take a look at asp.net identity, or even forms authentication.

Comment: Any suggested links for Forms Authentication @Alex